# Is there a VB6.0 OLE container replacement available for .net 4.0?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, activex, ole

I am in search of an OLE replacement of VB6 OLE container for .NET 2010 and searched online for the same.
I have found many posts which describe about MS Office application integration using WebBrowser component.Since my purpose of using OLE is not limited to MS Office those solutions will not work for me. One of the main challenges is CAD drawings. I need to use AutoCAD drawing (.dwg) file as part of OLE

I am aware of below preview handler class and found it will not serve my purpose since it’s not designed to handle AutoCAD drawing

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2012/01/23/Quick-replacement-for-the-VB6-OLE-Container-Control-in-NET.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/487566/OLE-container-surrogate-for-NET

in addition to OLE  if any of you know whether there is an ActiveX component through which I can edit AutoCAD  drawings will  be much appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: OLE is quite dead, it has been for over a decade.  .NET completely lacking any support for it helped hasten its well deserved demise.  Instead of embedding programs, programs now embed you.  AutoCAD has excellent support for writing add-ins with .NET.

Comment: @Hans: You did notice *VB6 OLE*? VB6 has been dead longer. :-)

Comment: I agree that it’s no longer alive but in even in recent releases of MS Office and other windows utilities like WordPad still support the object insertion option.
 
I wonder if these applications are supporting the OLE functionalities why I am not able to call the underlying MFC to achieve similar functionalities for my development